# I want sql query when one column has same value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I want to run a query in which all the column `number` has same value and copy the `address` value in the other other rows from the row in which value of `type` is 0.

For example in the posted image, where the `number` column has value '1', copy the address to other row of from `type` = 0.
That means all three rows where values of `number` column is 1, the value will of the address column will be ABC, ABC ,ABC and same in the `number` column where values are 2 , the address will be CSA,CSA.[image]

Comment: I am unable to think how to do, i need some help

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` and `select version()`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (take value for number with type = 0 and join it to a main table):

```
    WITH
    t AS (SELECT _number,
                 MAX(_address) AS _address -- here can be more than one row with type = 0 ?
              FROM test
              WHERE _type = 0
              GROUP BY _number)
SELECT test._id,
       test._number,
       test._type,
       t._address
    FROM test
    LEFT JOIN t
            ON test._number = t._number;
```

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fcb883443639466da4f304cdd6ce32ed) example

**upd.** for update you can use this one:

```
UPDATE test
    INNER JOIN (SELECT
    _number,
    max(_address) AS _address -- here can be more than one row with type = 0 ?
    FROM test
    WHERE _type = 0
    GROUP BY _number) t
ON t._number = test._number
SET test._address = t._address;
```

updated dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d169bfcd2cbeb9cfc16229f59ca0ad8c)

Comment: how can i update exact value to the existing table?

Comment: check updated post with dbfiddle